# Workflow not working when copy files uploaded

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, file-upload

I have a simple workflow, who copy items depending on the value of a field "CountryName", if equal CH, it copy the file in the folder CH ...
In SPD I checked the 2 choices to run the workflow if new item is added or modified.
When I publish the code, and I add a new file, I see in the source folder a  new column with the name of the workflow and the value "Completed", but in the destination folder it's empty. Any Idea please ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two common symptoms and the underlying causes of each is human error.  But don’t beat yourself up; they are easy mistakes to make and correct.  Use the following to troubleshoot the issue:

1. When a SPD workflow doesn’t copy one field to the target list:

   - The field names don’t match
   - The field names match, but the field type and the settings do not
2. In a document library, when none of the fields are copied (except the file name), or when all the fields are copied but intermittently:

   - The issue is that everything is working as designed and the workflow hasn’t accounted for it!  There is a difference between New and Upload

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I found that when I edit the properties of the file, it copy it where I want, But is there a way to do it once the file is uploaded ?

Comment: Are you working with Document library?

Comment: Yes, I have doc Lib 1 "Invoices", when a user enter upload a file and enter a countryname it's dispatched to folder of the country

Comment: Ok just find "The Difference Between New and Upload in a Document Library" from here...https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnwpowell/2009/01/02/sharepoint-designer-copy-list-item-workflow-activity-does-not-copy-all-fields/

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: I already "Set the workflow to execute only when the item is created", but the second point is no fair enough

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41315/discussion-between-hardik-and-bkchedlia).